# Time complexity of searching for target value in 2D matrix?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search, destructuring

The actual problem is pretty simple, implement an algorithm that returns true if the **target** value is contained within the **matrix**. Here are the two solutions I came up with. I'm not sure which one would be preferable? I believe solution 1 is faster since we don't need to build a new array, however would this be significantly faster?

Solution 1:

```
var searchMatrix = function(matrix, target) {
    let cols = matrix[0].length;
    let rows = matrix.length;
    let left = 0; 
    let right = cols*rows - 1;
    
    while(left <= right) {
        let midIndex = left + Math.floor((right-left)/2);
        let midValue = matrix[Math.floor(midIndex/cols)][Math.floor(midIndex%cols)];
        console.log(midValue);
        if(midValue === target) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(midValue < target) {
            left = midIndex + 1;
        } else {
            right = midIndex - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Solution 2:

```
var searchMatrix = function(matrix, target) {
    let arr = []
    for(let row of matrix) {
        arr = [...arr,...row];
    }
    let left = 0;
    let right = arr.length - 1;
    
    while(left <= right) {
        let middle = left + Math.floor((right-left)/2);
        if(arr[middle] === target) {
            return true;
        } else if(arr[middle] < target) {
            left = middle + 1;
        } else {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
    }
        
    return false;
};
```

Based on my understanding, the main step we're adding is converting the matrix into a regular Array. Would this make the algorithm O(n) since we have to add every element into the new array?

For solution 1, we don't have to create a new array so we'd have constant space correct?
I'm not particularly sure how to explain the first solution is preferable in terms of time/space.

Comment: In therms of time complexity is similar because you are using binary search so I can say that time complexity is O(log(n)), the first solution is O(1) in terms of space complexity, on the other hand the second is O(n), it dependes your limitations in terms of time and space, but for me the second one is more readable, another important factor when you are developing code.

Comment: @AndresReneGutierrezT exactly! I like the second one a lot more because it's a lot easier to understand what's going on. For an interview would you suggest using solution 2? Perhaps mentioning both and talking about the time complexity?

Comment: If you factored out a function that took a matrix and and overall index and did the conversion to fetch the value at the appropriate row/column, then the first version could be just as simple as the second, without extra storage and without changing the algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @ScottSauyet oh yeah! I think that would make a really good answer since it'd be optimized/more readable. Thank you sir.

Comment: @juanvicareer, I would choose the second in an interview, because you have to try to accomplish the three pillars, time and space complexity but also readability, so for sake of collaborative work, I would use the second solution.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments added to the post, readability and the ability to analyze the time complexity would yield the best answer. Perhaps the first option would be most ideal if we can make it more readable via a separate function used to calculate the matrix value.

Option 2 does take more space since we're creating an additional array to search through.